# Download CSV at client end by REST API In Nest JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a array of object data  from which I am creating a csv. After Generation Of CSV it should get  download at client side.At client side I am using Angular and at backend it is Nest Js.
I don't want to send link to client end to download csv . it  should be  done by REST API

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: so you are creating a CSV file on the server? or it's just the data?

Comment: @AZ_ I am creating CSV on the server

Comment: then `res.download('filepath')` will do the job.

Comment: @AZ_ it is giving me the link and to download CSV  and I have to click on Download file link. Can the file  automatically get download once I call my API?

Comment: @AkhileshJha is my answer below doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Youba I don't want do any operation at frontend. File should be automatically downloaded

Answer (score 3):

you can use this sendFile function from the Response, Exemple:

```
async DownloadFile(@Res() res) {
    try {
           ....
        return res.sendFile(pathfile, { root: './files' });
    }catch(e) {
       ...
    }
}
```

And for the frontEnd (as is in your case is Angular) you can use file-saver to download the file, to give you a hand, here is an example:

```
let FileSaver = require('file-saver'); // path to file-saver     
....
downloadFile(data: any) { // data : WebService response 
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'filename.csv');
 }
```

Comment: But there is no ```"pathFile"``` in server-side DownloadFile function... t's a generated json/csv variable. I have the same situation too btw

Comment: Do you mean the request comes from the frontend makes the rest API generate a file and you want to return it?

Comment: Yeah, the file is genrated from server-side and returned to client side @Youba

Comment: @Youba any way to provide both json and csv options automatically, I remember in Spring I could request /api/test.json or /api/test.csv and it would serialize the results to the correct format

Comment: you can do that here as well, you just need to add a parameter to the endpoint, if you need more explanation with code, don't hesitate to share with me your code on git or on new question